# How to use include tag in Maven dependency plugin

Tags: maven

I'm trying to unpack my dependencies using this [plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-project-dependencies.html)

The only issue is that I only want foo.jar to be unpacked but not moo.jar.
I'm guessing I have to use the include tag but I'm not sure how.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html#includeArtifactIds

Comment: What is the purpose for unpacking via maven-dependency-plugin ? What kind of project do you have?

Comment: It for a module inside another project which can't find class files within a jar within a jar. I'm sort of aggregating a bunch of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using the maven copy resources plugin to move folders around.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html